# What does pub in flutter stands for

Tags: flutter, dart, package

the title basically says it! What does pub in flutter stands for? the rest of this sentence is just top meet the question minimum characters

Answer (score 6):

From the description meta tag:

> [Pub](https://pub.dev/) is the package manager for the Dart programming language, containing reusable libraries & packages for Flutter, AngularDart, and general Dart programs.

So basically `pub` is the same as `npm` or any other package manager but it is specific to dart and flutter.